# How to sort NSPredicate

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, nspredicate

I am trying to sort my array while using NSPredicate.. I have read other places that possibly using NSSortDescriptor could be an option. Having some trouble figuring this out.

I am attempting to sort my array by companyName.

Any advice appreciated, thanks

Greg

```
- (void)filterSummaries:(NSMutableArray *)all byNameThenBooth:(NSString*) text results:(NSMutableArray *)results
{
    [results removeAllObjects];

    if ((nil != text) && (0 < [text length])) {        
        if ((all != nil) && (0 < [all count])) {
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"companyName contains[cd] %@ OR boothNumber beginswith %@", text, text];
            [results addObjectsFromArray:[all filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];        
        }
    }
    else {
        [results addObjectsFromArray:all];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you have several options how to sort an array:

I'll show a NSSortDescriptor-based approach here.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                  @"companyName contains[cd] %@ OR boothNumber beginswith %@",
                                  text,
                                  text];

// commented out old starting point :)
//[results addObjectsFromArray:[all filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];

// create a descriptor
// this assumes that the results are Key-Value-accessible
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"companyName" 
                                                             ascending:YES];
//
NSArray *results = [[all filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]  
                     sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];

// the results var points to a NSArray object which contents are sorted ascending by companyName key
```

This should do your job.

Comment: Thanks for response, I edited my main post to show a bit more code.

Doesn't predicate need to be used somewhere?

Comment: Sure. to lazy to type || copy'n'paste ;)

Comment: Can I do this using an NSMutableArray? I have an NSMutableArray named results being passed in as a parameter.

Comment: Basically yes. But you will loose the mutability temporarily. You have to send a mutableCopy afterwards and - most important - obey the rules of memory management by releasing the mutableCopy appropriately (e.g. with an autorelease pool)

Answer (score 4):

The `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` function walks through your array and copies all objects that match the predicate into a new array and returns it. It does not provide any sorting whatsoever. It's more of a search.

Use the sorting functions of NSArray, namely `sortedArrayUsingComparator:`, `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`, `sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:` and the like, whichever serves you most.

Checkout [NSArray Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) for details.

BTW: If you want to sort lexically, you may use `sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)` which will use NSString's `compare:` function to find the right order.