# Adding values to a particular index in core data

Tags: ios, core-data

```
// deleted all datas for entity before adding  

for (int i=0; i<[tempArray count]; i+=3)
{
    userData=(UserData *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserData" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    [userData setUserIcon:tempArray[i]];
    [userData setUserID:tempArray[i+1]];
    [userData setUserName:tempArray[i+2]];
    NSLog(@"loop values%@",[userData userName]);
}
```

The logged values give names in correct order. But the values stored in *core data* is not in proper order. E.g. value inside loop shows *(apple,ball,cat,dog)* but core data stored value shows *(apple,cat,ball,dog)*. I checked values in core data by :

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest1 = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"UserData"];
fetchRequest1.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
[fetchRequest1 setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"userName", nil]];
fetchRequest1.returnsDistinctResults = YES;

NSArray *dictionaries1 = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest1 error:nil];
NSLog (@"names after: %@",dictionaries1);
```

Any idea why order is mismatching ???

Also alternatively, can I add the values into *core data* for a particular index so that I can order the table myself?

Or can i use sorting, but i should sort the entire row as the attribute in a row are dependent to each other.

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous answer - your design based on insert order has no practical sense because such order can not be guaranteed and hard to maintain. 
The best practice is to apply sort predicates.
For instance you may go to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946642/how-to-sort-nspredicate)