# NSPredicate - Show exact match first

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I have a following array

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                @"Suresh",
                @"Dr. Akshay Phulare",
                @"Akshay",
                @"Ramesh",
                @"Dinesh",
                @"Akshay Phulare",
                nil];
```

And if I search, 'Akshay' using following predicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tagName CONTAINS[c] %@",containSearchTerm];
```

I'm giving following result: `["Dr. Akshay Phulare","Akshay","Akshay Phulare"]`

It's right because every string contains word 'Akshay'.

Current result is giving results according to sequence of words in array. But I want exact matches first and then remaining results. `["Akshay","Akshay Phulare","Dr. Akshay Phulare"]`

Comment: You have to either do this as two steps - 1. extract the array as you do at present and 2. sort based on your criteria. That is probably easiest, but you could also try to capture all that logic into a clever sort algo. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946642/how-to-sort-nspredicate

Comment: You need a custom sort. But you need to define what's the logic.. What if you had also `akshay` (case sensitive difference), what if you have also `"Akshay phulare"`? For non-exact match, what's the sort logic? Begins with first? Number of characters diffs? Initial place in the array, etc. Once you know all theses cases you can build your custom sort.